# browser-sync for SPA: how to sync document fragments: #/contact

Tags: single-page-application

I'm developing a SPA (Single Page Application) and use grunt-browsers-sync. 
All browser-sync features seem to work: CSS injection, scrolling and form synchronization.

It's a SPA so no navigation to other pages in done. Navigation is done via routes in the document fragment (I use the SammyJs library for this)

```
mysite.com/#/home
mysite.com/#/contact
mysite.com/#/...
```

It seems **BrowserSync doesn't synchronizes document fragments**.
I think it's because document fragments are handled by the browser and not requested at the BrowserSync server/proxy.

Is there some way to make the scenario work?

PS: I have a javascript callback when navigating, which I can use to send the new url to BrowserSync at development (if BrowserSync supports something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried using browser-sync for a single-page backbone application.

Routes changes are basically triggered on clicking anchors. Unfortunately, browser-sync doesn't play well with events having stopPropagation & hence, the click wasn't triggered in other browsers and routes were synced.

Since then I've forked and fixed this plus other issues namely event syncing for mouseup, mousedown, keyup, keydown and contenteditable div.

The [pull-request](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync-client/pull/23) is still pending though, so meanwhile you can use browser-sync-client from https://github.com/nitinsurana/browser-sync-client

You'll need to have configuration as follows for the fixes to take effect . Notice the capture, contenteditable, mouseup and other config options not present in browser-sync

```
var bs     = require("browser-sync").create();
var client = require("./");

client["plugin:name"] = "client:script";

bs.use(client);

bs.init({
    //server: {
    //    baseDir: ["test/fixtures"]
    //},
    proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
    open: false,
    minify: false,
    snippetOptions: {
        rule: {
            //match: /SHNAE/,
            match: /<\/head>/i,
            fn: function (snippet) {
                return snippet + "\n</head>";
            }
        }
    },
    clientEvents: [
        "scroll",
        "input:text",
        "input:toggles",
        "input:keydown",
        "input:keypress",
        "form:submit",
        "form:reset",
        "click",
        "contenteditable:input",
        "mouseup",
        "mousedown",
        "select:change"
    ],
    ghostMode: {
        clicks: true,
        scroll: true,
        forms: {
            submit: true,
            inputs: true,
            toggles: true,
            keypress: true,
            keydown: true,
            contenteditable: true,
            change: true
        },
        mouseup: true,
        mousedown: true
    },
    capture:true
});
```